# Animation of UILabel and UITextField (Facebook POP framework)

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, animation, facebook-pop

I'm using the Facebook POP framework to animate `UILabels` and `UITextFields` when the user entered a wrong input. I want to simulate the kind of spring animation when you enter the wrong password in on a mac.

I've writting this method for doing the shake animation:

```
- (void)shakeAnimation:(UITextField *)textField :(UILabel *)label
{
  //This method takes a textField and a label as input, and animates them accordingly. 
  //When the animation is done, the button is available for touch again, and the animation is removed.

  POPSpringAnimation *positionAnimation = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerPositionX];
  positionAnimation.springBounciness = 20; //just parameters, nothing fancy
  positionAnimation.velocity = @4000;
  [positionAnimation setCompletionBlock:^(POPAnimation *animation, BOOL finished) {
    self.signUpButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  }];
  [textField.layer pop_addAnimation:positionAnimation forKey:@"positionAnimation"];
  [label.layer pop_addAnimation:positionAnimation forKey:@"positionAnimation"];
  [positionAnimation removedOnCompletion];

}
```

However, When I'm calling this method like so: `[self shakeAnimation:self.emailField :self.emailLabel];`

the `UILabels` only move about 50px to the right and then stop moving, whereas the `UITextFields` don't do anything. It doesn't seem like an animation at all, just an adjustment of the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the same `POPSpringAnimation` to both the `textField` layer and the `label` layer, make two `POPSpringAnimation`s and add one to each. Like this :

```
POPSpringAnimation *anim1 = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerPositionX];
anim1.springBounciness = 20; //just parameters, nothing fancy
anim1.velocity = @400;
[anim1 setCompletionBlock:^(POPAnimation *animation, BOOL finished) {
    self.button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}];

POPSpringAnimation *anim2 = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerPositionX];
anim2.springBounciness = 20; //just parameters, nothing fancy
anim2.velocity = @400;

[textField.layer pop_addAnimation:anim1 forKey:@"positionAnimation"];
[label.layer pop_addAnimation:anim2 forKey:@"positionAnimation"];

[anim1 removedOnCompletion];
[anim2 removedOnCompletion];
```